# Como armazenar dados de um arquivo .txt em um objeto - Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arraylist

Eu sou iniciante em programação e estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação que deve cadastrar produtos, excluir, editar, organizar, controlar estoque, preço de custo, preço de venda, margem de lucro, etc.

Até agora eu consegui fazer com que um arquivo .txt armazene os objetos da classe produto em linhas diferentes, assim:

```
public void gravaProduto() throws IOException{

    FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter("E:\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Experimentacao3\\cadastro.txt",true);
    PrintWriter gravarArquivo = new PrintWriter(arquivo);

    for (Produto p : produtos) {
        gravarArquivo.println(p);
    }

    arquivo.flush(); //libera a gravaçao
    arquivo.close(); //fecha o arquivo
}
```

Também consegui ler o arquivo, assim:

```
public void leProduto() throws IOException{
    String linha = "a";

    FileReader arq = new FileReader("E:\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Experimentacao3\\cadastro.txt");
    //armazenando conteudo no arquivo no buffer
    BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
    //lendo a primeira linha
    //String linha = lerArq.readLine();
    //a variavel linha recebe o valor 'null' quando chegar no final do arquivo
    while (linha != null){
        System.out.printf("%s\n",linha);
        //lendo a segundo até a última
        linha = lerArq.readLine();

    }
    arq.close();

}
```

**O meu problema é:** (depois que a aplicação é encerrada e vou abrir ela depois) Preciso armazenar cada linha do txt em um ArrayList de objetos e depois fazer o que for necessário (ex: como ordenar por preço). Alguma luz? Estou no caminho certo? tem outra saída? Obrigado a todos!

Comment: É um trabalho de faculdade? Precisa ser mesmo arquivo texto? Poderia usar JSON? Porque não um banco de dados?

Comment: É um trabalho de um curso que eu fiz, o professor deixou aberto pra gente usar a criatividade e como é uma coisa que ele não ensinou teria que ser o mais simples possível, aí pensei em armazenar em arquivo txt (se é que é mais simples) mas pode ser feito de outra maneira... desde que eu entenda, pq sou iniciante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos! Consegui resolver assim:

```
    public void leProduto() throws IOException{

    FileReader arq = new FileReader("E:\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Experimentacao3\\cadastro.txt");
    //armazenando conteudo no arquivo no buffer
    BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
    //lendo a primeira linha
    String linha = lerArq.readLine();

    //ArrayListe para armazenar os objetos da leitura
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    //a variavel linha recebe o valor 'null' quando chegar no final do arquivo
    while (linha != null){
        //Criando o objeto p2 da classe produto
        Produto p2 = new Produto();
        //criando um array que recebe os atributos divididos pelo split
        String[] atributos = linha.split("#");

        //Se quiser usar outro separado use:
        //String[] atributos = linha.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

        //passando os "atributos" da array para o objeto p2
        p2.cod = atributos[0];
        p2.nome = atributos[1];
        //adicionando objeto p2 no ArrayList a
        a.add(p2);
        //capturando a proxima linha
        linha = lerArq.readLine();
    }

    /* Se quiser exibir o resultado (importante sobrescrever o método toString()
    for (Object p : a) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Você pode ler todas as linhas assim: `List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("arquivo.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Para usar **|** , no split, tente assim: **linha.split(Pattern.quote("|"));**

Answer (score -1):

Veja se lhe ajuda:

```
public class Exemplo {

    public static final String SEPARADOR = "#";
    public static final String ARQUIVO = "cadastro.txt";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        produto.setNome("Produto 1sss");
        produto.setPreco(15.5f);

        Produto produto2 = new Produto();
        produto2.setNome("Produto ddd");
        produto2.setPreco(25.5f);

        try {
            gravaProduto(produto);
            gravaProduto(produto2);


            List<Produto> produtos = leProduto();

            for(final Produto p : produtos){
                System.out.println(p.getNome()+", "+p.getPreco());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    /**
     * Adiciona o Produto, passado via parametro
     * @param produto
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void gravaProduto(Produto produto) throws IOException{
        FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter(ARQUIVO,true);
        PrintWriter gravarArquivo = new PrintWriter(arquivo);
        gravarArquivo.println(produto.gerarString());
        arquivo.flush(); //libera a gravaçao
        arquivo.close(); //fecha o arquivo
    }

    public static List<Produto> leProduto() throws IOException{


        //Lista que vamos retornar
        List<Produto> list = new ArrayList<Produto>(0);
        FileReader arq = new FileReader(ARQUIVO);
        //armazenando conteudo no arquivo no buffer
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        //lendo a primeira linha
        String linha = lerArq.readLine();
        //a variavel linha recebe o valor 'null' quando chegar no final do arquivo
        while (linha != null){
//          System.out.printf("%s\n",linha);
            //lendo a segundo até a última
            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            // Passamos a linha para popular o objeto, 
            // se não for vazia
            if(null != linha && !"".equals(linha) ){
                Produto produto = new Produto(linha);
                list.add(produto);
            }

        }
        arq.close();

        return list;

    }



    /**
     * Esta classe guarda a s informacnoes do Produtos
     */
    static class Produto{

        /**
         * Contrutor padrão
         */
        public Produto() {      }
        /**
         * recebe a linha para popular o Objeto
         * @param line
         */
        public Produto(String line) {   
            if(null != line ){
                //Vamos quebrar a linha no separador...
                String[] valores = line.split(SEPARADOR);
                // se não for nulo, vamos setar os valores
                if(null != valores){
                    setNome(valores[0]);
                    setPreco(Float.valueOf(valores[1]));
                    // se possuir mais campos, irá adiionar aqui, seguindo a ordem 
                }
            }
        }
        private String nome; 
        private Float preco;
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
        /**
         * Temos que garantir que esta String não possua o SEPARADOR
         * Senão irá bugar
         * @param nome
         */
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            if(null != nome){
                if(nome.contains(SEPARADOR)){
                    nome = nome.replaceAll(SEPARADOR, " ");
                }
            }
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        public Float getPreco() {
            return preco;
        }
        public void setPreco(Float preco) {
            this.preco = preco;
        }

        /**
         * Vamos concatenar os dados para salvar..
         */
        public String gerarString(){
            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if(null != getNome()){
                buffer.append(getNome());
            }
            //  inserimos ao separador
            buffer.append(SEPARADOR);
            if(null != getPreco()){
                buffer.append(getPreco());
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

    }
}
```